# Where can I find a good Finance Manager for Xubuntu 11.10?

Tags: xubuntu, 11.10, software-recommendation, finance

I am looking for a finance application that is similar to "SPB Finance" for my Pocket PC.

That program is simply money tracking with various graphs for a visual account of where your money is going. I don't need one for business management or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

I personally have never used SPB Finance, However I use gnucash for basic financial tracking. It pretty much has all the necessary functionality one would need to track money and can import your bank statements as well as generate basic graphs

```
#sudo apt-get install gnucash
```

if you don't like it...

```
#sudo apt-get purge gnucash
```

:)

You could also try the forums over at http://www.ubuntuforums.com and ask there, see if anyone has a better suggestion.

Comment: I have tried that actually and found that it was difficult to use and promptly removed it. I strongly recommend SPB Finance for your smartphone

Comment: I'll give it a look on my Android phone. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many options, actually. However, most of them aren't even close to SPB finance. I have used 352. GnuCash, Money Manager Ex and Financisto. Well, they are all good, but as I said above, SPB is ahead of all of them. The best one of these alternatives has to be Financisto. Honestly, that's a tremendous software that helped me a lot. GnuCash is also a prevalent choice, and it has better feedback than Financisto. I found out about them while learning how to start investing on https://www.moneyunder30.com/. The article about investing is fantastic!

Comment: @David It doesn't matter when the question was asked as long as the answers to the question are useful to the community. Ubuntu users don't have to be stuck in the past because of this one user who hasn't visited Ask Ubuntu for more than 8 years and obviously doesn't care about answers to this question anymore .